# How to remove trailing lines when appending to a file

Tags: python

The problem is when I add a student record (append txt to my file) for the first time a major blank gap is added

```
username,passcode

jack,Adidas123_
man,Adidas123_
kal,Adidas123_
ll,Adidas123_
```

I have tried to use the .strip() function it did not seem to help , I was expecting my csv file to appear like this

```
username,passcode
jack,Adidas123_
man,Ndidas123_
kal,Mdidas123_
ll,Zdidas123_
```

```
def add_user():
    infile = open("students.csv", "a")
    username = str((input('enter your username:')))
    passcode = "Adidas123_"


    data1 = f"\n{username},{passcode}"
    data = data1.strip() # strips white space
    infile.write(data +"\n") # appends to new line
    print('record added succesfully !')
    infile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by RandomCoder59.

Right now we can only see add_user() function in your sample code.

There is a possibility of you are adding newline via some other method to the same file.

```
infile = open("students.csv", "a")
```

"a" parameter here represents append mode. Please have a look into other methods in python code aswell. Hope this helps, Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in the original file that is being opened. You don't show its original value or how it was created. Likely, the file has starts with two new lines after the headers. The `strip` method won't have any effect on the data that is already in the file.

Take this example code (slightly adapted from your own):

```
def add_user(file, in_value:str):
    passcode = "Adidas123_"
    
    clean_value = in_value.strip() # strips white space
    line = f'{clean_value},{passcode}'
    file.write(line +"\n") # appends to new line
    print('record added succesfully !')
    return file
```

If I start with a file that has two new lines after the header:

```
file = io.StringIO('username,passcode\n\n')
file.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
```

Then I add two values, the first having a bunch of newlines, and the second having none:

```
# Add a username with a bunch of newlines
first_user = add_user(file, 'username1\n\n\n')
# Add a username with no newlines
second_user = add_user(first_user, 'username2')
```

The file contains the following text:

```py
'username,passcode\n\nusername1,Adidas123_\nusername2,Adidas123_\n
```

So you can see the values are being correctly added but there is an issue with the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, the problem must reside in your `students.csv` file. You may have by mistake left a newline in the file.

Check if you `students.csv` is:

```
username,password
```

or

```
username,password
```

with a newline.

Hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is not very elegant, but you could use your code as is and then take the empty line at the end. Basically your final text would be a string like this:

```
text_file = 'username,passcode\n\njack,Adidas123_\nman,Adidas123_\nkal,Adidas123_\nll,Adidas123_'
```

So you can just replace the double newline with a single one:

```
print(text_file.replace('\n\n', '\n'))

username,passcode
jack,Adidas123_
man,Adidas123_
kal,Adidas123_
ll,Adidas123_
```

For a better solution you should share more details of your code...